# Not able to import appwrite while making flutter app

Tags: flutter, docker, dart, cross-platform, appwrite

appwrite is added in my dependency still i am not able to import 'package:appwrite/appwrite/models.dart';
I am getting this
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:appwrite/appwrite/models.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist
package:appwrite/appwrite/models.dart

I want to use Account which is inside models i.e. models.Account
I am able to import 'package:appwrite/appwrite.dart' but not 'package:appwrite/appwrite/models.dart'
I have also tried importing 'package:appwrite/models.dart' this solve the problem of not able to import appwrite/models but still I am not able to use models.Account
I have tried updating dependency but still not able to figure out what is wrong.

I have tried running flutter pub get and also tried restarting vscode.

Answer (score 1):

So appwrite update this recently because Account class appears in both appwrite.dart and models.dart. So they changed Account to User. Try using models.User instead of models.Account

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to use `import 'package:appwrite/models.dart'` as the structure on GitHub implies https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-flutter/tree/master/lib

When you are using the import it should be enough to use Account instead of models.Account.

Alternatively you could use `import 'package:appwrite/models.dart' as models` and then use models.Account.

Here is an example project for using appwrite: https://github.com/appwrite/playground-for-flutter/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: I have tried that it solve the problem of not able to import appwrite/models but still I am not able to use models.Account